# Passing an Array to a Generic DataSource in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am implementing a generic datasource for TableView control. The part of the code is shown below:

```
class TableViewDataSource<CellType,ViewModel>: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource where CellType: UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier: String
    let cellType: CellType
    let items: [ViewModel]
    let configureCell: (CellType,ViewModel) -> ()

    init(cellIdentifier: String, cellType: CellType, items: [ViewModel], configureCell: @escaping (CellType,ViewModel) -> ()) {

        self.cellIdentifier = cellIdentifier
        self.cellType = cellType
        self.items = items
        self.configureCell = configureCell
    }
```

When I try to initialize the datasource in the view controller I get an error:

```
 private var datasource: TableViewDataSource<WeatherCell,WeatherViewModel>!

 self.datasource = TableViewDataSource(cellIdentifier: "WeatherCell", cellType: WeatherCell.self, items: self.weatherListViewModel.weatherViewModels) { cell, vm in

            // configure the cell

        }
```

When passing `self.weatherListViewModel.weatherViewModels` which is of type `[WeatherViewModel]` I get the following error:

```
Cannot convert value of type '[WeatherViewModel]' to expected argument type '[_]'
```

What does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This property is incorrect:

```
let cellType: CellType
```

This says that `cellType` is an instance of type `CellType`, but that's not how you're using it. You mean to pass the type itself and store it as a type parameter (rather than an instance variable). To do that, get rid of the `cellType` property entirely, and modify your `init` to accept `CellType.Type` rather than `CellType`. (You won't do anything with the `cellType` parameter; it exists only to specialize the class.

```
init(cellIdentifier: String, cellType: CellType.Type, items: [ViewModel], configureCell: @escaping (CellType,ViewModel) -> ()) {...}
```

Comment: Thanks Rob! That was it. I got confused because Xcode was giving incorrect error which was not making sense to me. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah; the error here should have been something like "WeatherCell.Type is not a subclass of UITableViewCell" (which would still be a somewhat confusing error, but at least is true; the metatype is not a subclass). When generic specialization goes off the rails, errors involving `_` are really common. They mean "something went wrong and I don't know what type should go there."